# MySQL count rows in a joint table

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I would like to count the number of rows or in this case the number of products which are in the same category and return zero if there are no products in the category.

The tables in my query looking like this:

```
category                    category_lang                 media
------------                -------------                 ---------
category_id | published     category_id | name | alias    media_id | category_id
-----------------------     --------------------------    ----------------------
1            | 1            1           | One  | one      1        | 1
2            | 1            2           | Two  | two      2        | 2
3            | 1            3           | Three| three    3        | 3

media_lang                          product_category
-------------------------------     ----------------
media_id | url      | file_name     product_id | category_id
-------------------------------     ------------------------
1        | /images/ | file1.jpg     1          | 1
2        | /images/ | file2.jpg     2          | 1
3        | /images/ | file3.jpg     3          | 2
```

and I would like a result like this:

```
category_id | category_name | alias | media_id | url      | file_name | count
1           | One           | one   | 1        | /images/ | file1.jpg | 2
2           | Two           | two   | 2        | /images/ | file2.jpg | 1
3           | Three         | three | 3        | /images/ | file3.jpg | 0
```

My query currently looks like this

```
SELECT 
c.`category_id`, 
ca.`name`, 
ca.`alias`, 
m.`media_id`, 
ma.`url`, 
ma.`file_name`,
COUNT(p.`product_id`) AS `count`
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN `category_lang` ca ON (c.`category_id` = ca.`category_id`)
LEFT JOIN `media` m ON (c.`category_id` = m.`category_id`)
LEFT JOIN `media_lang` ma ON (m.`media_id` = ma.`media_id`)
LEFT JOIN `product_category` p ON (c.`category_id` = p.`category_id`)
WHERE c.`published` = 1
ORDER BY ca.`name`
```

my logic is obviously wrong because this query will return this:

```
category_id | category_name | alias | media_id | url      | file_name | count
1           | One           | one   | 1        | /images/ | file1.jpg | 3
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: change `COUNT(p.product_id) AS count to COUNT(distinct p.product_id) AS count`  The issue is your count is being artificially inflated by a join which has multiple records per category.

Comment: For the life of me, I don't understand how you are getting those counts.  From what I see, all the counts should be one, and you should have just three records in the result set minus even adding `COUNT()`.  By the way, you should be using `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, but your expected output does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen take a second look. category one has 2 products, category two has 1 and category three has zero,

Comment: @LaciK I see it now, thanks for pointing this out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most painless (and sane) way to approach this would be to just aggregate the product counts for each category from the product_category table in a separate subquery, and then just join this to what you already have:

```
SELECT 
    c.category_id, 
    ca.name, 
    ca.alias, 
    m.media_id, 
    ma.url, 
    ma.file_name,
    COALESCE(t.cat_count, 0) AS cat_count
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_lang ca
    ON c.category_id = ca.category_id
LEFT JOIN media m
    ON c.category_id = m.category_id
LEFT JOIN media_lang ma
    ON m.media_id = ma.media_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) AS cat_count
    FROM product_category
    GROUP BY category_id
) t
    ON c.category_id = t.category_id
WHERE c.published = 1
ORDER BY ca.name
```

Note here that your `product_category` table does not have any category entries with no products.  This is not a problem, because in the `LEFT JOIN` we can simply treat a `NULL` count as being zero.  A `NULL` value would occur if a given category did not match to anything in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice solution and it works. Looking at your first comment I think you already posted the solution :) Adding `GROUP BY c.category_id` to my original query gives the same result as yours. Your answer is a good teaching example.

Comment: @LaciK Careful: Just adding `GROUP BY c.category_id` to your original query would give you invalid SQL which wouldn't even run on certain configurations of MySQL (and not at all on SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).  You can't just aggregate that way in general.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that it is where you are doing the count and that you doing have the criteria for doing the count. Adding an extra condition where product category id equals category id in your category table should fix the incorrect count.

```
SELECT 
c.`category_id`, 
ca.`name`, 
ca.`alias`, 
m.`media_id`, 
ma.`url`, 
ma.`file_name`,
COUNT(p.`product_id`) AS `count`
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN `category_lang` ca ON (c.`category_id` = ca.`category_id`)
LEFT JOIN `media` m ON (c.`category_id` = m.`category_id`)
LEFT JOIN `media_lang` ma ON (m.`media_id` = ma.`media_id`)
LEFT JOIN `product_category` p ON (c.`category_id` = p.`category_id`)
WHERE (c.`published` = 1) and (c.`category_id` = p.`category_id`)
ORDER BY ca.`name`
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but for me your syntax looks wrong. I thing adding count after FROM will trigger syntax error.

Comment: You're right. I pasted it in the wrong place. TYVM for catching it.